# How to get the last updated date of each url in my website, using c#

Tags: c#, xml, sitemap

I crawl my website and generate an xml sitemap. How do I get the date each page was last updated? The examples I find of c# code to create a sitemap just use the current date, or the last updated time in the response header, which is always the current date.

Also, if I include the time in the lastmod tag, what is the correct time format? does it need to end with an offset to the UTC as in 2009-04-15T13:23:26+0000

Comment: Please define "last updated date". How do you think this should be determined?

Comment: What are you using to create the sitemap? Custom code or a tool?

Comment: Are these pages stored on the filesystem or in a database?

Comment: Oded: refering to <lastmod> tag in Google's sitemap protocol.

Comment: Gregory: custom code. I would also like to generate sitemap for websites I do not have access to the server -I dont think I can get the actual file date in those cases

Comment: @Bill: what about pages that don't physically exist on disk? Those won't have a last modified date.

Comment: @BillSeacham: You can use Xenu Link Sleuth http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html to generate a site map file for any website.  I just created one for ww.google.com, I don't see how to change the `<lastmod>` to be UTC instead of just `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1):

Sample I was using in a vb.net website. `LastWriteTime()` method

**Last Updated:**

```
'Added in auto last updated time for website
Dim writeTime As String
writeTime = String.Format(
  My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(
    Me.Server.MapPath(Me.Page.Request.Path)).LastWriteTime,
  "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS")
Response.Write(writeTime)
```

Comment: what if I want to generate a sitemap for a website that I dont own/have server access to? It seems to me all I can do in that case is use current date or not include the lastmod tag.

Comment: So is your question really, "What is the correct format for `<lastmod>` tag"?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemap_index#Time_format_for_.3Clastmod.3E_tag

Comment: Doug: 2 questions. one is how to get the date of the file if I dont have access to the server? I am doing an httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse -I dont think I can get the actual datetime stamp of an html file that way. Other question is the format -which I think has to be
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD 2007-08-25T00:00:00+00:00
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD 2007-08-25T00:00+00:00
YYYY-MM-DD 2007-08-25